# Unity8 & Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, unity8

I use Ubuntu 15.10 on my Netbook and it works great. Now,I have a question. When I want to install Unity8 on an existing OS, will anything change on the software I already installed?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can run multiple desktop environments: LXDE (included in Lubuntu), GNOME (included in Ubuntu GNOME), MATE (Ubuntu Mate), Unity (included in plain vanilla Ubuntu) without your underlying software being affected.

That being said, if you run KDE, some software might have to get more libraries pulled in but a simple `sudo apt-get MySoftware --reinstall` will accomplish that.

Comment: Drive-by user... +1 from me